# How to "android media player" (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer

Here's the situation - I've started studying kotlin and android studio, and now I'm stuck with this.
I have a button (ImageView) that when pressed starts to play an audio file.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mp: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var bruhSound: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(R.raw.bruh)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        bruhBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (mp == null) {
                controlSound(bruhSound[0])
                bruhBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btnpressed)
            } else if (mp !== null) {
                bruhBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun controlSound(id: Int) {
        if (mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, id)
            Log.d("MainActivity", "ID: ${mp!!.audioSessionId}")
        }
        mp?.start()
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Duration: ${mp!!.duration / 1000} seconds")
    }
```

Currently when I press "bruhBtn", the picture is changing to "btnpressed" and back again correctly, but it wont change after audio is ended. I want it to reset on the audio finishing. I realize that problem is with my code, I need to change the image when the audio is finished. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your line

```
mp?.start
```

add a listener

```
    mp?.setOnCompletionListener { //change your button state here }
```